# How does damage versus Zyra's Plants work?

Tags: league-of-legends

Zyra's plant summons all have 6 hitpoints, yet they often survive multiple hits from champions.

I assume this means they are similar to Wards (3 hp, 1 hp per attack), but the plants seem able to take more than 1 hp of damage at a time, so it's not an identical mechanic.

What determines how much damage Zyra's plants take?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All plants can killed by 3 AAs from Champs or one single target spell and one AA.

Minion Damage is treaten diffrently, but from a siege minion one shot equals one bar. Turrets instantly kill the plant (one shot).

**EDIT**:

- Single-Target spells do 4 damage each (2 bars).
- AOE abilites deal 1.5 damage each. (per tick if applicable, like Morgana's tormented soil)
- DoTs deal .5 damage each tick.
- smaller mobs (including neutrals) do 1 damage per auto attack (1/2 a bar) .
- bigger creeps (big wraith, big golem etc) and champions do 2 damage (1 bar) per auto attack.
- Towers kill the plants instantly (6 damage).

**EDIT2**:

[From Reddit: Zyra's Plants Take Damage in Extremely Buggy Ways](http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/xm5d7/zyras_plants_take_damage_in_extremely_buggy_ways/)

Comment: how much damage does one champion auto attack do?

Comment: 1/3 of the plants health, independent on AD.

Comment: So the gist of it is, "Zyra's plants are buggy, and take damage inconsistently, currently". Well that's fun... :/ Thanks for updating your info and providing another source!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Jacimovski's excellent answer, Morgana's pool takes off half an hp "bar" per tick from the plant, so it kills it in 6 ticks. This seems really relevant given Zyra's role as a mage (ie mid).

Then again I've found it best to just ignore the plant they cast near me and drop my pool on the minions, then last hit the plant for a free 5g.

Comment: true. What you have to know about these plants is 1. they prioritize the target of Zyras AAs, so if she is not autoattackign you, the plants focus nearby minions, not you; and 2. if you step on a seed, you dont take any dmg or negative effect ebside beein revealed for 2 sec. If you have any dash ability (gragas E, for example) you can dash over it, activating them so zyra cant use them! be cerafull tho, if she just laid them down they have 1-2 sec "cd" where they dont proc.